# Dynamically populating checkbox from database using ajax

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, checkbox

I am new with JQuery. (I want to do it using AJAX, JQuery, PHP)

I am trying to dynamically populate a list of checkboxes from the database.

What I have is a drop down. Based on the selected option I want to query the database, and depending on the recordset I want to dynamically display the checkboxes.

Any suggestions

```
<script>
     $(function(){
        $("#softwareapp").change(function(){
           if($(this).val() > 0){
           var app_id = $('#softwareapp').val();    
           $.ajax({         
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>ajaxcalls/get_softwareappversions/"+app_id,
                data:{savid = $(this).val()},
                success: function(data){
                      var _table = $("<table></table>");
                      for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
                          $("<tr></tr>").append($("<td></td>").html("<label><input type='checkbox' value='data[i]' name='softappver[]'/>" + data[i] + "</label>")).appendTo(_table);
                      }
                      $("#displayappversions").html("").append(_table);
                }
           });
           }
        });
     })
```

For some reason this has stoped working. I am trying to get rid fo the table stuff.

and following is my HTML:

```
<select name="softwareapp" id="softwareapp">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">SAP</option>
    <option value="2">SAGE</option>
    <option value="3">SWIFT</option>
</select>


<div class="form-row"> 
    <p class="form-label">Application Version</p>
    <div class="form-item" id="displayappversions">
        <!--- VERSIONS ARE SUPPOSE TO COME HERE--->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use google and stack previous posts for suggestion..write some code on your own an if you feel any problem with the code handling let us know then :)  REFER : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#vendor").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() > 0){
        $("#displayappversions").load("<?php echo base_url(); ?>ajaxcalls/get_softwareappversions/" + $(this).val());
    }
  });
});
```

My ajax call is returning HTML that makes the list of chcek boxes.